# RadTelerik Datepicker showing above the control

Tags: telerik

I am using telerik datepicker

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker id="radDatepicker" runat="server">
     <ClientEvents OnPopupOpening="OnPopupOpening" ></ClientEvents> 
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

The datepicker is placed inside a modal. When modal is opened and user clicks on the datepicker the raddatepicker popup is positioned incorrectly.

```
<div class="RadCalendarPopup RadCalendarPopupShadows" style="position: absolute; border: 0px; z-index: 5006; left: 869.5px; top: 658px;">
```

default rendered top position - 658px
expected top position - 760px

Is there any way i can refer RadCalendarPopup and set the top position. I used jquery $("RadCalendarPopup") but it doesnt work, maybe because it is not rendered at the time when i am setting its top value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to programmatically control the position of the DatePicker's popup:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server" >
    <ClientEvents OnPopupOpening="ShowDatePopup" />
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
<script>
    var isCanceled = false;
    function ShowDatePopup(sender, args) {

        if (!isCanceled) {
            isCanceled = true;
            args.set_cancel(true);
            sender.showPopup(100, 100);
            isCanceled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```